# How to connect two tuples from one table to one tuple from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: *users* and *waybill*. Each tuple from the waybill corresponds to two tuples from the user.

When viewing a record in a table, the *loginManager* value is displayed in the *loginManager* and *loginStorekeeper* columns.

Can I modify the query so that the names of the storekeeper and manager are not duplicated or do I need to add a new table to the database?

*User.Name* field is repeated because the names of the storekeeper and manager are in the same table

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Waybill.Id
     , Waybill.IMO
     , Vessel.Name
     , Waybill.loginManager
     , User.Name //manager login and name
     , Waybill.loginStorekeeper
     , User.Name
     , Waybill.Date //storekeeper login and name
  FROM Waybill
     , Vessel
     , User 
 WHERE Waybill.IMO = Vessel.IMO
   AND Waybill.loginManager = User.Login
   AND Waybill.loginManager = User.Login
 ORDER 
    BY Waybill.Id
```

*Waybill*

```
+-------------------+--------------+
| id                | INT(11)      |
| IMO               | INT(11)      |
| LoginManager      | VARCHAR(300) |
| LoginStoreKeeper  | VARCHAR(300) |
| Date              | DATETIME     |
+-------------------+--------------+
```

*User*

```
+----------+--------------+
| Login    | VARCHAR(300) |
| Password | VARCHAR(300) |
| Name     | VARCHAR(300) |
| Phone    | VARCHAR(20)  |
| Role     | VARCHAR(50)  |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: I know that the problem is easily solved by adding tables to the database, however I would not really like to modify the database.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: My first suggestion would be to rewrite the query using modern explicit JOIN syntax. Implicit "comma" joins have been considered archaic and clumsy for decades now. Rewriting with explicit joins would at very least make the duplicate join conditions in your WHERE a little more obvious.

Comment: Uueerdo, may i ask you for an example

Comment: Always use schema, instead of image. It is more easier to recreate table and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without adding tables, you can solve the problem like this:

```
SELECT WaybillTable.Id
, WaybillTable.IMO
, VesselTable.Name
, WaybillTable.loginManager
, UserManagerTable.Name
, WaybillTable.loginStorekeeper
, UserStorekeeperTable.Name
, WaybillTable.Date 
FROM Waybill WaybillTable 
INNER JOIN Vessel VesselTable 
ON WaybillTable.IMO = VesselTable.IMO 
INNER JOIN User UserManagerTable 
ON WaybillTable.loginManager = UserManagerTable.Login 
INNER JOIN User UserStorekeeperTable 
ON WaybillTable.loginStorekeeper = UserStorekeeperTable.Login 
ORDER BY WaybillTable.Id
```